# How to transfer files between two computers with a server in the middle?

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a PC-1 in my home and need to transfer files back and forth to my PC-2 at my University.

The problem is that PC-2 has only access to local network.

So, in order to access it from home I have to ssh to the University server and only then ssh to PC-2.

I know that scp can transfer files between two PCs, but did not find anything in documentation for when there is a server in the middle.

Can it be done with scp or other tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scp with a second remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139417/how-to-scp-with-a-second-remote-host)

Comment: And [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative answer if the ssh tunnel is disabled on the server side :

- `PC-2` to `PC-1`

  `ssh university-server 'ssh PC-2 "cat remotefile"' > localfile`
- `PC-1` to `PC-2`

  `ssh university-server 'ssh PC-2 "cat > remotefile"' < localfile`

Explanation :
You are asking `university-server` to ssh to `PC-2` with the specified command ( in this case `cat`) and using pipe redirection to write or read from local files

PS: Modified the answer according to working correction in the comment

Comment: `PC-2` to `PC-1` works like a charm, thanks.
but not the other way around

Comment: the problem was missing quotes, this works `ssh university-server 'ssh PC-2 "cat > remotefile"' < localfile`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [ssh tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol), to connect to `PC-2` from `PC-1` using `university-server` as an intermediate.

1. Establish the tunnel

   `ssh -f -N university-server -L 2222:PC-02:22`

   the tunnel will be kept in background until the `ssh` process is killed
2. scp file transfert

   - `scp -P 2222 user@localhost:file .`
   - `scp -P 2222 file user@localhost:path`

Comment: I can estabilish the tunnel, but when I run scp it hangs. Stays as if it processing, but no response after more than a minute.

Comment: could you test the tunnel by using `ssh -p 2222 user@localhost`, or could you ping `PC-2` from `university-server` ?

Comment: The `ssh` test shows this message **channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed \
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host**

Comment: also, unfortunately depending on the ssh server configuration, ssh tunneling might be disabled by the administrator.

Comment: no, when I try the `ssh -p 2222 user@localhost` I get that message. but what I can do is ssh to `university-server` and then ssh to `PC-2`