# Host key verification failed in script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh, key, pem

I have created AWS VPC . In that VPC **5** ec2 instances are created, **ONLY 1** Instance is publicly accessible other **4** instances are in ***private network***.

i am using script to transfer war file from my **local machine to Pubilcly accessible server and then it will transfer to private server .**

I am using same pem file all server , so during scp command it will transfer war file from  local machine to publicly accessible server but it will **failed to transfer war file from publicly accessible to Private server** .

It gives the error:

```
Host key verification failed!
```

Script commands :

1. **Transferring from Local machine to publicly accessible server.**

   ```
   scp -p portno -i ./Test.pem ./Test.war ec2-user@publicly_accessible_server_ ip:/home/ec2-user/
   ```

> > Working fine It will transfer local to publicly accessible server.

2. **Transferring from publicly accessible server  to Private Server.**

   ```
    ssh -p portno -i ./Test.pem ec2-user@**publicly accessible server ip** "scp -P portno -i /opt/IdentityFiles/Test.pem /home/ec2-user/Test.war ec2-user@**private_server_ip**:/home/ec2-user/"
   ```

> > Not able send war files from publicly accessible server to private server gives error Host verification failed**

permission pem file are working .

Note :**suppose i run the second command from terminal it works , but in script it is not working !**

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: [How to scp with a second remote host

Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139417/how-to-scp-with-a-second-remote-host)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scp with a second remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139417/how-to-scp-with-a-second-remote-host)

Comment: A better architecture pattern is to upload the war file to S3 and access it via the AWS S3 command line, that way you have no need for a public server and can control access to the S3 bucket via IAM roles and policies.