# How to transfer files from AWS server to local machine where the AWS server is behind Bastion server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, file-transfer, scp

How to transfer files from AWS server to local machine

Following is the way all the machines are located

`AWS machine -> Bastion server -> Local machine`

I have copied the files from AWS machine to Bastion server and Bastion server to local machine with SCP command

Following are the two steps I have done

1. ssh into bastion server
   Copied file from AWS instance to Bastion server

`scp user@ipaddress:~/test1.txt ./`

2. From my local machine, I have executed the following command

`scp user@bastion:~/test1.txt ./`

I would like to automate with a single script which needs to be triggered from my local machine for copying files from AWS instance to local machine

Comment: SSH to bastion and copy the file from the server to bastion. Now, copy the file from bastion to your local machine.

Comment: The above mentioned way works. But I would like to copy the files from server to bastion from local

Comment: Drop the final copy step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to copy files to the Bastion server. In fact, from a security perspective, extremely little should be stored on a Bastion server.

Instead, there are two methods you can use to directly connect to the "AWS machine" via the Bastion.

- Proxy Jump
- Port Forwarding

See:

- [Using ProxyJump with SSH and SCP](https://www.madboa.com/blog/2017/11/02/ssh-proxyjump/)
- [How to scp with a second remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9139417/174777)
- [mperdikeas.github.io/networking.html.files/scp-a-file-through-jump-host.html](http://mperdikeas.github.io/networking.html.files/scp-a-file-through-jump-host.html)
- [Using SCP to transfer files to a private EC2 instance through a Bastion Host](https://www.davidbegin.com/using-scp-to-transfer-files-to-a-private-ec2-instance-through-a-bastion-host/)