# How do I scp from a second remote host, that requires a key, to the local machine?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, file-transfer, scp, ssh-agent

I regularly transfer files from a second remote host to my local machine. It would be nice to do this in one go! However, I need to load a key to connect to the second remote host.

Usually, the process is first to connect to the intermediate host:

```
ssh user@host1
(enter password)
```

I then load my private key and transfer the file from the third host to the second host:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id-privatekey

scp user@host2:filename filename
```

Then finally exit the second host and transfer the file from the second host to my local machine

```
exit

scp user@host2:filename filename
```

This is time-consuming, and a bit of a pain for large files where the disk space on host1 is limited.
The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139417/how-to-scp-with-a-second-remote-host) question, so I tried:

```
ssh user@host1 'exec ssh-agent bash && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id-privatekey && ssh user@host2 "cat filename"' > filename
```

which seems to log into the first host, but nothing more. Please could anyone help?